# What does the underscore positive sign mean outside a parentheses?

Tags: statistics, multivariable-calculus

I know this might be a simple question but in the equation $\sum(|y_i − w^T x_i − b| − \epsilon)_+$ does the underscore positive sign mean $(|y_i − w^T x_i − b| − \epsilon)>=0$ ?

Comment: It's not a 100% standard notation; my guess would be $(t)_+$ means $\max\{t,0\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may mean the "positive part" of the expression.

Generally, one writes $f = f_+-f_-$, where $f_+$ is the positive part of $f$ and $f_-$ is the negative part of $f$. These are the values
$$f_+ = \tfrac12(|f| + f)$$
$$f_- = \tfrac12(|f| - f)$$
Note that these are both nonnegative.

If $f\geq 0$, then $f=f_+$.

If $f\leq0$, then $f = -f_-$.